# How to prevent Netbeans 8 from stopping on the first line when debugging a PHP Application

Tags: php, xdebug, netbeans-8

I'm working on a PHP application for a web server in Netbeans 8.0.1. I've installed XAMP/Apache Server/XDebug and can run and debug the application. When I debug the project in Netbeans, the debugger breaks at the beginning of each php file. This is very annoying and interrupts the process of debugging. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Netbeans -> Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Debugging, and uncheck the 'Stop at First Line' checkbox.