# Shortened value in Netbeans PHP debugger

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a WordPress plugin that dynamically creates a big SQL query. The plugin itself does not assemble the whole query, but it hooks the `posts_clauses` action and it sends the components of the query to WP. Then the WP query.php file assembles them in a single string variable. I set a breakpoint into the plugin code, then I step through the calls into query.php and reach the point where WP builds the SQL string. I'd like to copy this string, but it's so long that Netbeans shows ellipsis and the word "shortened" before the string is completely shown.

I'm using NB 8.2 on Linux, PHP 5 and xdebug. In NB `Options|PHP|Debugger` tab I've already entered 16384 for the "Maximum data length" and I've already dropped the following line into the xdebug configuration file:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_data=16384
```

I've already restarted Netbeans and Apache, but the problem persists. The part of the SQL string shown is exactly 2000 characters long.

I know I could hook `posts_pre_query` WP action, and log the query, but hell, I'm debugging, I don't want to add throw away code that forces me to change the sources after they have been debugged and tested...

How do I make NB show PHP string values longer than 2000 characters in the debugger?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat it's not a Wordpress question, I mentioned WP only to give context, but WP here is actually almost irrelevant.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yes it is, but, if you read the question, you easily realize that my problem has nothing to do with WP. WP is there only to explain why I can't just echo the SQL statement.

Comment: For debbug query why you not dump It in the screen? I'm not familiar with NetBeans debbuger in PHP ... Check this link if it can be a help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528819/how-to-prevent-netbeans-8-from-stopping-on-the-first-line-when-debugging-a-php-a

Comment: @JoaquinJavi I don't understand how that question relates to mine. However I can't dump the SQL query because the debugger shows me only its first 2000 characters.

Comment: Yes I mean make a var_dum($sql)... And see it through the browser , and the another thing was just a suggestion!

Comment: According to the documentation, using `-1` as value should remove any limitations. That goes for the other `var_display_max...` settings as well.

Comment: @JoaquinJavi I could insert `var_dump($sql)` into the WP code, because the $sql variable is only there. I could also enable the MySQL log and take the query from there. The point is: I have a debugger, it seems to have the options to show long variables and I'd like to use it. In perspective it's a useful tool if it worked, more efficient than any other workaround.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I've tried with -1 but the debugger stops working at all (Error connecting to xdebug...)

Comment: It's not Xdebug but Netbeans. I confirmed it using `tcpdump` to sniff traffic of debugging session on long, well known string (note, Xdebug uses base64 encoding to encode string variable contents). Xdebug sends complete string to NetBeans so it must be NetBeans that truncates it with "[shortened]" at the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After digging through NB source code I've found solution. `nb.php.debugger.full.values` property controls whether or not values are truncated. To disable variable truncation edit your netbeans.conf file and add `-J-Dnb.php.debugger.full.values=true` to the end of `netbeans_default_options` option:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dnb.php.debugger.full.values=true"
```

Restart the IDE afterwards.

I didn't need to change NB settings through configuration before so this might not be the best way to do it.